# Disable previous dates and change date format in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, datetime-format

How can I disable previous dates on datetimepicker? Currently I'm using the code below, but it also disables the current date. The format also includes time which I don't want either.

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    disabledDates: [new Date()]
});
```

Expected format: 09/17/2020 
Actual format: 09/17/2020 10:34 PM

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "disable previous date format 'mm/dd/yy'" - do you mean you want to change the date format? Or disable dates up to today? Also, `disabledDates` isn't an option for the jQuery date picker, so are you using a different date picker, e.g. Bootstrap?

Comment: I wanted to disable the previous dates in my datetimepicker so user wont be able to select past dates also how can I format my datetimepicker for to mm/dd/yy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both jQuery UI `datepicker` and jQuery `datetimepicker` plugin, the options you are looking for are:

- **Disable dates before today**: `minDate: 0`
- **Change date format to `mm/dd/yy`** (e.g. 09/17/20): `dateFormat: "mm/dd/y"`
- **Change date format to `mm/dd/yyyy`** (e.g. 09/17/2020): `dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"`

In `datetimepicker`, you can also have the following options:

- **Disable specific dates**, e.g.: `disabledDates: ['01/01/2021','01/02/2021','01/03/2021']`
- **Disable the timepicker**: `timepicker:false`

Or if you don't want the time, then you can just use `datepicker` :)

This is how to initialise your datetimepicker with these options:

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    timepicker:false,
});
```

**Working Example using datepicker**:

```js
$("#my_datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<label>Date</label>
<input id="my_datepicker" type="text">
```

References: [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), [datetimepicker plugin](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)